# Evaluating $ \int \ln(\sqrt{1 + x} + \sqrt{1 - x}) ~ \mathrm{d}{x} $.

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I evaluate the indefinite integral above? I have tried integration by parts, but it has only served to make the problem more complex.

Comment: No, parts is the correct approach.

Comment: Can you please guide me/give some hints? :)

Answer (score 3):

Continuing with integration by parts,

HINT:

$$\dfrac{x}{2(\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x})}\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+x}}-\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-x}}\right)=\dfrac{x(\sqrt{1-x}-\sqrt{1+x})}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}(\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x})}$$

$$=\dfrac x{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}\cdot\dfrac{(\sqrt{1-x}-\sqrt{1+x})^2}{1-x-(1+x)}=-\dfrac{1-2\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Now follow [this](http://www.sosmath.com/tables/integral/integ13/integ13.html)

Comment: Hmm but for the first line of your equation,

I can't get them to equal. Can you please recheck?

Comment: @kengchi, Please find the updated answer