# How do I integrate an unseparable function in the form $\displaystyle\int\ln(\sqrt{1-x} +\sqrt{1+x})\,dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

How do I go about doing this:

$\displaystyle\int \ln(\sqrt{1-x} +\sqrt{1+x})\,dx$

I have tried substituting but I couldn't find a suitable substitution. How do I go about simplifying this problem to go about integrating it?

Comment: Apparently this can be done by first integrating by parts with u as the logarithm

Comment: I hope it has caused you to get a good idea how to continue

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1998837/evaluating-int-ln-sqrt1-x-sqrt1-x-mathrmdx/1998856?noredirect=1#comment4104313_1998856

Answer (score 2):

> Using integration by parts:
>
> $$\int\text{f}\left(x\right)\text{g}\space'\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x=\text{f}\left(x\right)\text{g}\left(x\right)-\int\text{f}\space'\left(x\right)\text{g}\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x$$

---

So, in your problem:

$$\mathcal{I}\left(x\right)=\int\ln\left(\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x}\right)\space\text{d}x=\int1\cdot\ln\left(\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x}\right)\space\text{d}x$$

Now:

1. $$\text{f}\left(x\right)=\ln\left(\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x}\right)\space\to\space\text{f}\space'\left(x\right)=-\frac{x}{2\left(1-x^2+\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)}$$
2. $$\text{g}\space'\left(x\right)=1\space\to\space\text{g}\left(x\right)=x$$

So, we get:

$$\mathcal{I}\left(x\right)=x\ln\left(\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{x^2}{1-x^2+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\space\text{d}x$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $$I = \int \ln(\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x})dx$$

put $x=\cos 2 \phi\;,$ Then $dx = -2\sin 2 \phi d \phi$

So $$I = -2\int \ln \left[2\cdot (\cos \phi + \sin \phi )\right]\cdot \sin 2 \phi d \phi$$

So $$I = -2 \ln (2)\int \sin 2 \phi d \phi -2 \int \ln (\sin \phi+\cos \phi )\cdot \sin 2 \phi d \phi$$

Integration by parts for second, We get

$$I = \ln (2)\cdot \cos 2 \phi -2\left[-\frac{1}{2} \cos 2 \phi \ln (\sin \phi+\cos \phi)-\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{\cos \phi - \sin \phi}{\sin \phi+\cos \phi}\cdot \cos 2 \phi d \phi  \right]$$

So $$I = \ln (2)\cdot \cos 2 \phi +\cos 2 \phi \ln (\sin \phi+\cos \phi)+\int \cos 2 \phi d \phi$$

$$I =\ln (2)\cdot \cos 2 \phi +\cos 2 \phi \ln (\sin \phi+\cos \phi)+\frac{1}{2}\sin 2 \phi +\mathcal{C}$$

$$I = \ln (2)\cdot x+x \cdot \ln\left(\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-x^2}+\mathcal{C}$$

Comment: No, it must be $\displaystyle -\frac{x}{2}+x\ln( \sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x})+\arctan\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}+C$ .

Answer (score 0):

I use Jan's answer as a basement.

> > Using integration by parts:
>
> $$\int\text{f}\left(x\right)\text{g}\space'\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x=\text{f}\left(x\right)\text{g}\left(x\right)-\int\text{f}\space'\left(x\right)\text{g}\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x$$
>
> ---
>
> So, in your problem:
>
> $$\mathcal{I}\left(x\right)=\int\ln\left(\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x}\right)\space\text{d}x=\int1\cdot\ln\left(\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x}\right)\space\text{d}x$$
>
> Now:
>
> 1. $$\text{f}\left(x\right)=\ln\left(\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x}\right)\space\to\space\text{f}\space'\left(x\right)=-\frac{x}{2\left(1-x^2+\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)}$$
> 2. $$\text{g}\space'\left(x\right)=1\space\to\space\text{g}\left(x\right)=x$$
>
> So, we get:
>
> $$\mathcal{I}\left(x\right)=x\ln\left(\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{x^2}{1-x^2+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\space\text{d}x$$

$$\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{x^2}{1-x^2+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\space\text{d}x = \frac{1}{2} \int(-\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2 (x-1)}+\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2 (x+1)}-1) \space\text{d}x $$

$$\frac{1}{2} \int(-\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2 (x-1)}+\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2 (x+1)}-1) \space\text{d}x = -\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \int(-\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2 (x-1)}+\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2 (x+1)}) \space\text{d}x $$

$$\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2 (x+1)}-\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2 (x-1)} =\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} $$

Therefore

$$\frac{1}{2} \int(-\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2 (x-1)}+\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2 (x+1)}) \space\text{d}x = \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}  \space\text{d}x = \frac{\arcsin(x)}{2}$$
$$\mathcal{I}=-\frac{x}{2}+x \ln \left(\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{x+1}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \arcsin(x)$$
You can find a derivative and check yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$I = \int \ln(\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x})dx = \frac{1}{2}\int 2\ln \left(\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}\right)dx$$

So $$I = \frac{1}{2}\int \left[\ln \left(\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}\right)+\ln \left(\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}\right)+\ln \left(\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}\right)-\ln \left(\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}\right)\right]dx$$

So $$I = \frac{1}{2}\int \ln(2x)dx+\frac{1}{2}\int \ln \left(\frac{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}\right)dx$$

Put $x=\cos 2 \phi \;,$ Then $dx = -2\sin 2 \phi d \phi$

$$I = \frac{x\ln 2}{2}+\frac{1}{2}(x\ln x-x)-\int \ln \left(\frac{\cos \phi +\sin \phi}{\cos \phi -\sin \phi}\right)\cdot \sin 2 \phi d \phi$$

Using Integration by parts, We get

$$I = ''\cdots \cdots +\frac{1}{2}\cdot \ln \left(\frac{\cos \phi +\sin \phi}{\cos \phi -\sin \phi}\right)\cdot \cos 2 \phi+2\int\frac{\cos \phi+\sin \phi}{\cos \phi-\sin \phi}d \phi$$